# Using result of first select statement into another and store result into another table

Tags: mysql, sql

After a lot of reading I have written these 3 sql statement and I want to automate and combine these 3 sql statement.

```
select longitude,latitude from roadData;

SELECT geo_coordinates_latitude, geo_coordinates_longitude,
 ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians('-37.964637158') ) * cos( radians( geo_coordinates_latitude ) ) * 
 cos( radians( geo_coordinates_longitude ) - radians('144.408476215') ) + sin( radians('-37.964637158') ) *
 sin( radians( geo_coordinates_latitude ) ) ) ) AS distance 
 FROM tweetmelbourne HAVING distance < .1 ORDER BY distance LIMIT 0 , 20;

Insert into roadTweets(longitude,latitude) values(144.408476215,-37.964637158);
```

**

> What basically i want to do is pick all the coordinates from roadData
>   one by one and then find all the point in tweetMelbourne within 20
>   miles of it and insert those point into another table.

**

> describe tweetmelbourne;

[image]

> describe roadData;

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'm not enterily sure on this, so please let me know if this works:

```
Insert into roadTweets(longitude,latitude) values(SELECT geo_coordinates_latitude, geo_coordinates_longitude,
 ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians(SELECT latitude FROM roadData) ) * cos( radians( geo_coordinates_latitude ) ) * 
 cos( radians( geo_coordinates_longitude ) - radians(SELECT longitude FROM roadData) ) + sin( radians(latitude) ) *
 sin( radians( geo_coordinates_latitude ) ) ) ) AS distance 
FROM tweetmelbourne HAVING distance < .1 ORDER BY distance LIMIT 0 , 20);
```

Comment: Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'SELECT geo_coordinates_latitude, geo_coordinates_longitude,  ( 3959 * acos( cos(' at line 1

Answer (score 0):

I guess this should be:

```
    select * from tweetmelbourne t, roadData r 
where distance(r.longitude,r.latitude,t.geo_coordinates_longitude,t.geo_coordinates_latitude) < 20;
```

And either implement distance funcion or replace distance(r.longitude,r.latitude,t.geo_coordinates_longitude,t.geo_coordinates_latitude) with formula calculating distance so. In oracle you can use package SDO_GEOMETRY.

Comment: Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'latitude' in 'field list'

Comment: @kapcer i have included the description of table

Comment: Please try now. I've edited the answer. However the logic of calculating distansce is a bit weird for me. What distance are you going to calculate?

Comment: i think i confused you. I have updated the question let me know if u didnt understood yet.

Comment: So it looks you just want to take cross join of those tables filtering points that have distance less than 20