# using first sql statement result into another sql statement

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin, mysql-workbench

What basically i want to do is pick all the coordinates from `roadData`
one by one and then find all the point in `tweetMelbourne` within 20
miles of it and insert those point into another table.

So for every `(x,y)` in `roadData` table find neighbouring data point from
`tweetMelbourne` and insert those points into another new table.

So I have to do this:

```
SELECT geo_coordinates_latitude, geo_coordinates_longitude
 FROM tweetmelbourne
 HAVING  ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians(latitude) ) * cos( radians( geo_coordinates_latitude ) ) * 
 cos( radians( geo_coordinates_longitude ) - radians(longitude) ) + sin( radians(latitude) ) *
 sin( radians( geo_coordinates_latitude ) ) ) ) < .1 ORDER BY distance LIMIT 0 , 20;
```

in which the value of latitude and longitude i have to get from another table :

```
select longitude,latitude from roadData;
```

describe tweetmelbourne;

[image]

describe roadData;

[image]

```
SELECT geo_coordinates_latitude, geo_coordinates_longitude
FROM tweetmelbourne;
```

[image]

```
select longitude,latitude from roadData;
```

[image]

Comment: You need to separate it into two subqueries, `WHERE x in (...) AND y in (...)`.

Comment: This makes no sense. The `WHERE` clause is used to select rows in `student`.

Comment: How are the `student` and `tweet` tables related to each other? Is there a `student_id` column in the `tweet` table?

Comment: But i wanted to do that only so let output of first query is 5 rows. Now i want to run second query against every 5 rows.

Comment: Show some sample input and the desired output.

Comment: @Barmar My main question was http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39943264/using-result-of-first-select-statement-into-another-and-store-result-into-anothe

Comment: i j ust shortened it so that somebody can answer

Comment: You shouldn't post a new question, you should have edited the original question. But neither of them is very clear on what you really want to do. You don't seem to understand what `WHERE` means in SQL, which is a very basic thing.

Comment: What database - MySQL or Oracle?

Answer (score 0):

The correct syntax of `IN()` with multiple arguments is : `(Val1,Val2) IN(SELECT VAL1,val2..`

```
SELECT t.address,(t.x+t.y) as z 
FROM student t
WHERE (t.x,t.y) IN(SELECT x,y FROM tweet)
```

Also can be done with a join :

```
SELECT t.address,(t.x+t.y) as z 
FROM student t
JOIN tweet s
 ON(t.x = s.x and t.y = s.y)
```

**EDIT:** I think what you want is:

```
SELECT s.address,t.x+t.y as z
FROM student s
CROSS JOIN tweet t
```

Comment: Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'x' in 'field list'

Comment: Do you have a column x in table student ? @ArjunChaudhary

Comment: nope. I want to use output of  second query  as input to first one.

Comment: basically my main question was this but i thought nobody want to read complex so i shortened it . http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39943264/using-result-of-first-select-statement-into-another-and-store-result-into-anothe

Comment: That doesn't make any sense, that where clause is basically : `SELECT .. WHERE <DATA> IN(<Same_DATA>) . It will always be true. Please explain what are you trying to do.

Comment: I think i have confused you. The thing is both table are not related. What i want to do is use output of first query as input to another like a for loop. So,,  for (every row in result 1){ run query2 with result of query 1}

Comment: Yes, that is what `CROSS JOIN` in my edit query does. Each record of `tweet` will be joined to each `address` in student @ArjunChaudhary

Comment: SELECT geo_coordinates_latitude, geo_coordinates_longitude,
 ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians(latitude) ) * cos( radians( geo_coordinates_latitude ) ) * 
 cos( radians( geo_coordinates_longitude ) - radians(longitude) ) + sin( radians(latitude) ) *
 sin( radians( geo_coordinates_latitude ) ) ) ) AS distance 
 FROM tweetmelbourne
  where (longitude, latitude) in (select longitude,latitude from roadData)
 HAVING distance < .1 ORDER BY distance LIMIT 0 , 20;

Comment: why above query giving error Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'latitude' in 'field list'

Comment: Why is it not able to get it from where clause... it must be because selectis executed frst but is there any way to execute the 3 parameter after where clause

Comment: @ArjunChaudhary PLEASE edit the question and show sample input and desired output. It's impossible to tell what you're really trying to do.

Comment: @ArjunChaudhary It's giving an error because the `tweetmelbourne` table doesn't have a `latitude` column, and you said to select all the rows in that table whose `latitude` is in the result of the sub-query.

Comment: @Barmar I have added properly

Comment: @ArjunChaudhary No you haven't. You haven't shown any data, and you haven't shown the desired results.

Comment: It looks like you should be joining the `geo_coordinates_latitude` and `geo_coordinates_longitude` columns of of `tweetmelbourne` with the `latitude` and `longitude` columns of `roadData`.

Comment: @Arjun Chaudhary I don't think the where clause is required - try sagi's suggestion of a cross join to road data.

Comment: @Barmar I think i have confused a lot i have added partial result of both query and at last what I require.

Comment: @Barmar  now do you guys get what i am saying? ot is it still confusing.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT s.address, (t.x + t.y) as z
from (SELECT id,x,y FROM `tweet`) as t, student s
WHERE t.id = s.id;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to join the two tables, calculating the distance in the `ON` clause to select the nearby rows.

```
SELECT *
FROM tweetmelbourne
JOIN roadData
ON ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians(latitude) ) * cos( radians( geo_coordinates_latitude ) ) * 
    cos( radians( geo_coordinates_longitude ) - radians(longitude) ) + sin( radians(latitude) ) *
    sin( radians( geo_coordinates_latitude ) ) ) ) < .1
```

This will be very slow if the tables are large. It's not possible to use indexes to implement the join, so it will have to perform that complex formula on every pair of rows. You might want to look at MySQL's [Spatial Data](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/spatial-extensions.html) extensions.

Comment: SELECT geo_coordinates_latitude, geo_coordinates_longitude,
 ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians(latitude) ) * cos( radians( geo_coordinates_latitude ) ) * 
 cos( radians( geo_coordinates_longitude ) - radians(longitude) ) + sin( radians(latitude) ) *
 sin( radians( geo_coordinates_latitude ) ) ) ) AS distance 
 into roadTweets
 FROM tweetmelbourne
  cross join  roadData
 HAVING distance < 20 ORDER BY distance LIMIT 0 , 20;

Comment: I think this would be also be good. Yes its very slow.. How to use spatia; data. I ll try that and then ask you if its ok.